# Why is my resultant signal not appearing correctly? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I have written some code below in MATLAB to filter a Noisy signal (`noise_f` is the noisy signal, where it is a `1` x `256` vector):

```
s_nf = size(noise_f);
size_f = s_nf(2); 

lp_tresh = ceil((2/3)*size_f);  
lp_f = zeros(1,256); 
for n = 1:lp_tresh
    lp_f(n) = noise_f(n); 
end
subplot(4,3,7);
plot(abs(lp_f)); title('LowPass Filter Result');
```

Here is a time domain image of the noisy signal:

[image]

Here is a time domain analysis of this signal:

[image]

Once I plot the result of the lowpass filter, I get this:

[image]

Now I apply the `ifft` on the `1` x `256` vector that represents the filtered signal and for some reason, I get this image :

[image]

Can someone explain to me how to get the proper plot of the filtered signal? All help and suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: you completely remove the negative frequencies, which results in a complex signal.

Comment: poor mans solution: take the real part of the ifft result and multiply by 2.

Comment: @AndreasH. Is it because, we are filtering out a harmonic of the fundamental, that we are getting half the magnitude?

Comment: @AndreasH. I also do not see any negative frequencies, is the `ifft` causing them?

Comment: The negative frequencies are the upper half of the vector fft() returns. When you apply a lowpass filter it should be symmetric around the the center point of the DFT vector. Yours is not, which removes the negative frequencies, causing a complex signal.

Comment: You also see the symmetry of the harmonic signal in the FFT plot, dont you?

Comment: @AndreasH. got most of it except for the fact that removing negative frequencies makes the signal complex. Why is that? Also, I guess we have an answer to this question?

Comment: a real signal is always symmetric in frequency domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a strictly real result, the input to an IFFT must be complex conjugate symmetric.  Chopping off the part of the FFT above bin N/2 (or below bin 0) destroys that symmetry if any of those bins are non-zero.

Thus, a low-pass filter will only work in the frequency domain if it's cutoff is below bin N/2 (representing Fs/2).  Then make sure the filtered result is conjugate symmetric before doing the IFFT.